# Как заполнить поля на сайте для POST запроса

Tags: c#, post

На сайте есть два поля-календаря, которыми задается интервал дат, за который необходимо получить информацию из БД. Никак не могу понять, каким образом POST запросом я могу передать нужные мне значения в поля выбора дат, и запустить скрипт на выполнение.

Пытался разобраться с примерами из интернета. С их помощью удается получить html разметку страницы, без её содержимого, т.к. содержимое генерируется js скриптом с параметрами описанными выше.

Вопрос может показаться глупым, т.к. только начал изучать ЯП.

Comment: Поля выбора дат - это `UI`. Вам не нужно с ними взаимодействовать. Вы должны понять, какой именно запрос на основе этих полей формируется и куда отправляется. А в этом Вам может помочь режим отладки в браузере (F12 -> Network).

Comment: Можно чуть подробнее. Про консоль браузера тоже уже прочитал несколько статей, но что именно там искать, так  и не разобрался. Возможно есть какой то доходчивый материал по этой теме? Буду благодарен за наводку.

Comment: Увы, хороших статей я не знаю, но дело не сложное. Я делаю так: 1) Открываю режим отладки (F12 -> Network) 2) Очищаю список, чтобы не запутаться 3) На странице заполняю нужную форму и отправляю её 4) В отладчике просматриваю каждый запрос, который ушёл на сервер при отправке формы. 5) Нахожу необходимый (тут уже никакого универсального гайда нет, потому что почти все сайты уникальны, просто рутинное просматривание.)